How does 我感到最大的成就就是影响了一代又一代人对自己的看法 not imply 自己影响了别人?
From 《新汉语水平考试HSK（六级）攻略：听力》, the following is part of an interview (it's the 5th interview of 听力第02部分2; OCR by Yandex):

男：在美容界用“泰斗”这个词形容您也不为过，在美容界这么多年，您觉得最大的成就是什么？
女：我感到最大的成就就是影响了一代又一代人对自己的看法，自己是可以改变的。如果今天我的皮肤看起来不是特别好，我可以用一个东西改变它。我们用颜色改变了中国人生活的方式，这是很重要的改变。 (photo of original)

and we're asked to answer this question:


女的认为自己最大的成就是什么?
A 自己影响了别人
B 创造了自己的品牌
C 使大家变得更漂亮
D 自己成了著名人士

C：女的觉得她影响了大多数人的想法，让大家明白了自己是可以改变的。  (photo of original)

I chose A, because it's so similar to the part in bold, especially the use of the verb 影响.  The given answer is C (with the above explanation), but I don't see how 漂亮 fits into this (although perhaps it's used figuratively).  I'm not sure if I'm missing something important here.
Question: How does 我感到最大的成就就是影响了一代又一代人对自己的看法 not imply 自己影响了别人?

我觉得，这就不是中国话。这个“自己”是指“说话的人”，还是“别人”？

“看法”的意思通常是指“对一件事情的看法”，是主观的印象，。“皮肤“，”美容”，等是物理的，客观的。应该是“面容”。

Because 我可以用一个东西改变它。我们用颜色改变了中国人生活的方式 also implies she influences "lots of people" instead of just some of people. C implies larger impact than A thus C is the answer.

OK,as a Chinese,I can tell you your answer is absolutely right.And your understanding is correct too! The only possible problem is the choice a is a more general statement,and the problem want a more detailed explanation.

第一次对自己的母语水平不自信了自己是可以改变的完全不符合语言习惯，就像是被采访人紧张而语无伦次了

It is a tricky question. 自己 (oneself) here doesn't refer to 我自己 (I, myself),
You have to read it as:
我感到最大的成就就是影响了一代又一代人对(他们)自己的看法，(人)自己是可以改变的
I feel my greatest achievement is to influence generations of people to change their view of themselves - that oneself can indeed, change.
One cannot become beautiful if she doesn't believe she can change. The speaker changed their mind and made them believe beautification can help change themselves
Answer C "使大家变得更漂亮" is the correct one, because people started to believe they can change, and everyone becomes more beautiful (because they start to do something for their appearance)
Changing people's opinion of her is not an achievement (成就), at least not the greatest achievement (最大的成就); Making everyone beautiful is a great achievement

My view is that "Making everyone beautiful..." is not her great achievement, but that having people change or influence the peoples' perceptions of themselves, (影响.....对自己的看法) is her greatest achievement, and she did it by making people more beautiful through the beauty industry.

I must agree with the opinion that the given answer, C, is wrong. A is the only correct answer. I asked 2 Chinese friends their opinion and both immediately said A.
The woman said:
我感到最大的成就就是影响了一代又一代人对自己的看法，
I think (my) greatest success is influencing how generations of people see themselves,
自己是可以改变的。
(and that) they can change themselves.
女的认为自己最大的成就是什么?
A 自己影响了别人
There is some confusion between the 2 自己 in 自己最大的成就 and 自己是可以改变的, the former meaning her and the latter meaning themselves.
3 points for those in desperate pursuit of beauty:
1. Beauty is in the eye of the beholder.
2. Beauty is only skin deep.
3. You’re only pretty as you feel. (Grace Slick)


我感到最大的成就就是影响了一代又一代人对自己的看法.
Yes, it is not an easy question to answer right.
My translation would be:-
"I believe / feel that my greatest achievement is being able to influence, (or have an impact on), how generations of people see / view themselves"
Q:- why "not imply 自己影响了别人?"
Well, B & D are obviously inappropriate.
So, it is a toss up between A & C.
It is "C" because 自己影响了别人 means just, "Influencing other people", (which is partly correct in the context of the sentence in question, hence the "trap" set in answer A)
It is "partly" correct because in 影响了一代又一代人对自己的看法 there is influence of course, but the "influence" here goes towards how "...people see / view themselves", (对自己的看法), differently because here the female speaker, being in the beauty industry, is able to "cause" generations of people to "see / view" themselves differently, (or change perceptions of themselves) just by "becoming more beautiful", 变得更漂亮.
Thus the question is not just "influencing" other people, but the end result, the consequence of her influence which is to change how people see / view themselves, 影响....对自己的看法
So, the question is not just having a bare influence, (which 自己影响了别人 simply means), but how the influence goes on to have an impact on how generations of people see / view themselves, (positively), after benefitting from the beauty industry by becoming more beautiful.
Therefore her greatest achievements are in having generations of people change the way they see / view themselves in knowing "change" is actually possible just by becoming more beautiful owing to the beauty industry of which the female speaker is a practitioner.
Side Comment:-
This speaks volumes about the inculcated vanity of people who have an enhanced sense of self-esteem just by becoming more beautiful. This I might add applies equally to both genders. The film industry of course plays a huge part. I once asked by Niece-in-Law, who is Korean, whether the people of Korea, (in South Korea of course), all look like the film stars in Korean soap operas, and she replied, of course not.

"女的认为自己最大的成就是什么?

A) 自己影响了别人(対美容的看法)
B) 创造了自己的品牌
C) 使大家变得更漂亮
D) 自己成了著名人士"

The correct answer unarguably will be "A", as it is indeed a great achievement for those who can influence a group of people's attitudes and change their minds toward something. We can argue that "A" is an incomplete answer without the change/correction, but we can't say it is wrong, as she did influence and change minds.
The answer "C - 使大家变得更漂亮(making everybody more beautiful)", without further explanation, is rather the result (成果) of her achievement (成就) - "改變了大家対美容的看法, 意識到美容是改善外觀讓自己更亮麗的有效辦法, 結果是使大家变得更漂亮".

Yes, at first glance option A seems to be the correct choice which was why I said it was partly correct. However, A seems too glaringly obvious as exam questions are seldom that easy, and therefore too good to be true, or as George Bernard Shaw said, too true to be good. So, C is most likely the correct answer without really knowing why as both B & D are completely incorrect. Under the pressure of an exam, (without the luxury of time to ponder), a leap of faith would have to do and opt for C and hope for the best since examinees need not give reasons for their answers.

@WayneCheah Fully understand your point. If that is the only question on the exam, half of the class might have failed :)

Which half would you fall into :)  ?

@WayneCheah I don't know how to put up a crying face :) sigh!

How about this  (;_;)

The answer is wrong. This is a simple logical conclusion.
如果今天我的皮肤看起来不是特别好，我可以用一个东西改变它。 This applies only to those people who think their skin isn't good enough. It certainly doesn't apply to those whose skin is good. In other words, it only applies to a subset of people, not everyone. In answer C,大家 means everyone. 使大家变得更漂亮 means making everyone more beautiful. This certainly is not what the text says.
女的觉得她影响了大多数人的想法，让大家明白了自己是可以改变的。 To me, 大多数人 is not 大家.
